# Is there a way to pass object's method as the parameter in java?

Tags: java

I have 1 class as mentioned below:

```
public class mathAdd {

public int add(int val1,int val2) {
    int res = 0;
    res = val1+val2;
    return res;

}

}
```

I want to pass the method "add" as a parameter something like the way shown in the code below?

```
public class test4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test4 t4 = new test4();
        mathAdd m1 = new mathAdd();
        t4.testMeth(m1.add);
    }
    public void testMeth(Object obj.meth()) {

    }

}
```

Is it possible to do this?? if yes how will I achieve this

Comment: What is your real goal ?

Comment: Take a look at interfaces in [`java.util.function` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Comment: As like JavaScript and other functional programming languages , we can pass method definition as parameter to another method . This is new feature introduced as part of Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. A way to pass an existing method as argument is to make the target method itself take a functional interface type, and then you can use a method reference for the method you want to pass as argument:

```
public void testMeth(IntBinaryOperator method) {
    //IntBinaryOperator defines a method that takes 2 ints and returns an int
    //And that's the signature matching mathAdd#add

    //you can call the method using something like
    int result = method.applyAsInt(int1, int2);
}
```

And then in `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test4 t4 = new test4();
    mathAdd m1 = new mathAdd();

    t4.testMeth(m1::add); //pass the 'add' method
}
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the return type that you want to pass, and not the method. when you write

`t4.testMeth(m1.add());`

it will pass return type of the function which is int type, so you need to write testMethod's parameter as,

```
public void testMeth(int funResult) {

}
```

Comment: While this does solve the errors, it doesn't answer the actual question